# Pronunciation of God's Name in the Bach

Tags: shemos-sacred-names, pronunciation, acharonim, tur

The *Bach*, writing on the *Tur* *OC* 5:1, says that when pronouncing the tetragrammaton (שם הויה) as the שם אדנות, some people say the first vowel as a *patach* and some as tending toward *tseirei*.  His words:

> מקצתם קורים בפתח ומקצתם קורין נוטה לצירי וכן הוא מנהג האשכנזים

Other commentators discuss the distinction between a *patach* and a *shva*, and many talk about using *chataf patach*, however I have not seen any other discussion of this "tending toward *tseirei*" besides those who quote the *Bach*.

**Does the *Bach* mean *tseirei* the same way we do?** (From the *Be'er Heiteiv*, who quotes the *Bach*, and from the discussion of the *Be'er Heiteiv* in *siman* 6 *seif katan* 2, it would seem that he at least understands the *Bach* to mean a *tseirei* the same way we do.)

**Does this pronunciation persist today?** The *Bach* says that the "tending toward *tseirei*" pronunciation is the common *minhag* of *Ashkenaz*, so one would expect that it does survive.

Comment: I'm unaware of any pronunciation system where the place of articulation between a patah and a seirei isn't a segol, and I don't know of any Ashkenazi pronunciation where segol and seirei are completely merged. I wonder what he meant by "tending towards seirei."

Comment: @ShamanSTK Could it be the "a" as in "bat"?

Comment: @Scimonster the bat a is technically between the segol and patah. The Yemenites merged the two letters at this mid point, but that's a Babylonian tradition. I'm not aware of any Ashkenazi tradition that uses that sound for a patah or a sere.

Comment: @ShamanSTK, interesting comment. Perhaps for his pasak in his community he was drawing on a tradition through the Gaonim. Many things from the Temanim come via the Gaonim. See this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Sirkis

Answer (score 1):

You're right. "tending toward *tseirei*" is exactly equivalent to the *shva* that you already heard about. When a *shva* is in the beginning of a word, it sounds very similar to a *tseirei*, just quicker. That's probably what the *Bach* meant by "tending toward *tseirei*".

A semi-proof for this we see in *Mishna Berura* (same place) where he says:

> ... וגם בנקודת אדנ"י, דהינו האלף בחטף-פתח ...

Since he remarks in *Sha'ar HaTsiun*:

> דלא כמהר"מ והב"ח

Opening up the mentioned *Maharam* ([*Shut Maharam Lublin*, siman 83](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1937&pgnum=76)) brings a long answer about reading the *aleph* with a *shva*, which again, must be a *shva na*, which sounds like a *tseirei*.

The *Sha'arei Teshuva* says that *Maharam* retracted this opinion (same place of *Mishna Berura*).

So it seems that even though there were a few *poskim* who said that the *aleph* should be read in *shva*/*tseirei*, most of them agree that it should be read as we all do today.

I myself have never heard of anyone with a tradition of reading it with a *shva*.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, and welcome to Mi Yodeya! I hope you stick around and enjoy reading and contributing to the site; you may especially enjoy our 140 other [tag:pronunciation] questions and our 29 [tag:mishnah-berurah] questions.

Comment: I really enjoyed reading this answer, but I don't fully understand it (or the comments on the question that are similar). What does "sounds like a Tzeirei" mean? I don't pronounce Sheva (aka [schwa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa)) Na' that way. I don't know anyone that does, actually. In fact, my college professor for Arabic, whose PhD was in Aramaic, argued that a Sheva Na' should be pronounced like the 'u' in the English word "urge", and not like the 'i' in "hit" as most do (nor as the 'e' in "egg", as this pst seems to recommend - if I've understood you correctly). Can you clarify?

Comment: Indeed, thank you for this answer, but I have the same issue as @SethJ.  I don't understand how a *sheva na* is pronounced as "tending toward a *tseirei*".  I've seen other opinions (besides those in the above comment) that *sheva* should be a shorter version of the following vowel (so in this case, a short *o*), but not as a *tseirei*.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome, and I find your comments very interesting. I live in Israel, where even in the Ashkenazi community many of the Sephardic customs have taken hold. Here the most popular way to pronounce a *shva na* is like a *tseirei*, but quicker. Here's a very interesting source about *shva* in general:
http://forum.otzar.org/forums/download/file.php?id=27146
Paraphrasing:
This custom (*shva na* like a *tseirei*) is mentioned by the later grammarians: *Ma'ase Efod*, R' Shabtai Sofer, *Maharal*, *Minchat Shai*, **Bach**. It is known as an "Eretz Israel" pronunciation.